# Mysql Subtraction low performance

Tags: mysql, select

I am making the following query in my applicattion, that retrieves rows:

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    SUBSTRING(description, 1, 200) AS s_description, 
    refresh_time, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-refresh_time) AS since, 
    state, state_friendly, 
    city, city_friendly, 
    category, category_friendly, 
    basename, COUNT(ad_id) AS im_ocur
FROM `ad` `a` 
JOIN `state` ON state_id = ad_state_id 
JOIN `city` ON city_id = ad_city_id 
JOIN `category` ON category_id = ad_category_id 
LEFT JOIN `ad_image` ON ad_image_ad_id = ad_id 
WHERE (ad_country_id = 195) 
GROUP BY `ad_id` 
ORDER BY `refresh_time` DESC, front DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I have tested it at many situations, but when referring to a city with lots of rows, performance it's been decreased. After several changes i realized that the problem was due because of "(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-refresh_time)" expression, so it seems Mysql Engine make arithmetic operations before the row limitation is set to 20.

My alternative solution is post-processing data with PHP, but i prefer the full mysql way.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is nothing with the return column using mathematical function, but simply caused by the GORUP BY on lots of rows.

Comment: But when i delete that expression the performance is excellent despite using GROUP BY

Comment: Did you try to use EXPLAIN for this query ?

Comment: Because the query is already query ... Try `SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF;`and you will notice both equally slow if not

Comment: I tried `SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF` and performance stills good if i dont use `(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-refresh_time)` expression. I dont know the problem itself, but thats what i can see, tested with 2100 rows, limited to 20.

Comment: Queries with temporal functions (like UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) are not cached anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a substraction, but UNIX_TIMESTAMP() being called for each row (I might be wrong though).

If you think substraction is the reason of low performance, you can always move it to outer query.

```
SELECT
  title, 
  s_description, 
  refresh_time, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-refresh_time) AS since,
  state, state_friendly, 
  city, city_friendly, 
  category, category_friendly, 
  basename, im_ocur
FROM (
  SELECT 
    title, 
    SUBSTRING(description, 1, 200) AS s_description, 
    refresh_time,
    state, state_friendly, 
    city, city_friendly, 
    category, category_friendly, 
    basename, COUNT(ad_id) AS im_ocur
  FROM `ad` `a` 
  JOIN `state` ON state_id = ad_state_id 
  JOIN `city` ON city_id = ad_city_id 
  JOIN `category` ON category_id = ad_category_id 
  LEFT JOIN `ad_image` ON ad_image_ad_id = ad_id 
  WHERE (ad_country_id = 195) 
  GROUP BY `ad_id` 
  ORDER BY `refresh_time` DESC, front DESC 
  LIMIT 20
) AS sq
```